# Problem with drop-down menu

Tags: selenium, webdriver, java, ie9

I'm new to Selenium Webdriver and I have a problem with a dropdown menu. I compiled my code but sometimes it returns the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == i_ACAD (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Sometimes it executes the script normally.

I really do not know how to resolve this problem.

A piece of my html code:

---

```
<li id = "i_ACAD" title="Register">
<a class ="TemSub" tabindex="25"> Register </a>
</li>

<li id = "i_MPG" title="Menu Payment Profile"> 
 <a class="TemSub" tabindex="45"> Payment Profile </a>
</li>
```

---

My code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frmmenusuperior")));

Thread.sleep(3000);

WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='i_ACAD']/a"));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

actions.moveToElement(menu).perform();

WebElement submenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='i_MPPG']/a"));

Actions subactions = new Actions(driver);

subactions.moveToElement(submenu).perform();
```

Answer (score 3):

Check with different xpath & use implicitly wait instead of 'Thread.sleep'
-See below

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frmmenusuperior")));   
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='i_ACAD']/a"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);   
actions.moveToElement(menu).perform();

WebElement submenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='i_MPPG']/a"));   
Actions subactions = new Actions(driver);   
subactions.moveToElement(submenu).perform();
```

Comment: Thank you, but it not resolved my problem, I continue with the same problem.

Comment: plz attach screen of your drop down  here....

Answer (score 0):

Use following code that may help :

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frmmenusuperior")));
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    WebElement menu=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li[@title='Register']//a"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(menu).perform();
    WebElement submenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li[@title='Menu Payment Profile']//a"));
    Actions subactions = new Actions(driver);
    subactions.moveToElement(submenu).perform();
```

Please let me know if it helps